# MUI CSS, textfield padding changing when input values are introduced

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the textfield of MUI in Chrome (not in Firefox). When I write an input, the padding changes (but I dont find any difference in the code). Im trying to find the difference in the CSS but I can not. Any idea what could be happening?

[image]

[image]

```html
<table class="maintable" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin-bottom: 10px">


<th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 18px; padding-bottom: -20px">

<table style="margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: -10px">
<th>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
<input type="text" id="width" maxlength="5" title="Width of the room (meters)" onblur="update(); showrecomendations()"/><label>Width (m)</label>
</div>
</th>
<th>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
<input type="text" id="height" maxlength="5" title="Height of the room (meters)" onblur="update(); showrecomendations()"/><label>Height (m)</label>
</div>
</th>
<th>
<div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
<input type="text" id="length" maxlength="5" title="Length of the room (meters)" onblur="update(); showrecomendations()"/><label>Length (m)</label>
</div>
</th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried ur code snippet in both Safari and Chrome. It works fine.
I think the problem maybe using the  tag roughly.

```
<table class="maintable" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
<th style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 18px; padding-bottom: -20px">
<table style="margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: -10px">
```

Normally we the  tag could embed another  tag. It may not cause the whole project crash. However, sometime the browser could translate the code in a wrong way.
Moreover, if u want to it to be a whole part and display like a block, you could use  tag.